# Tkinter Radiobutton: Image pixelated on OSX but works fine in Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, radio-button, tcltk

I've implemented a grid of Radiobuttons each having a unique image.

I've included relevant lines of code below:

```
photo[i] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)
button[i] = Radiobutton(frame, variable=var, value=i+1, indicatoron=0, image=photo[i], selectcolor='#808080')
button[i].pack(side=LEFT)
```

The image on OSX looks very pixelated as can be seen below:

[image: OSX Pixelated Radiobutton]

The same code works just fine with ubuntu (no visible pixelation). Below is the original image:

[image: Original Image]

Comment: cannot reproduce, it looks perfect on `osx 10.12.5` - maybe post the entire code (including imports) you are using to display the image.

Comment: I have 10.15.6 but I don't think so that should be a source of error. Could you please provide the code you write, so that I can check it on my machine? Thanks.

Comment: Tried @ReblochonMasque code on my system. Still the image is pixelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the system version of tcl tk as mentioned [here](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).

> If you are using macOS 10.6 or later, the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5
> has serious bugs that can cause application crashes. If you wish to
> use IDLE or Tkinter, do not use the Apple-supplied Pythons. Instead,
> install and use a newer version of Python from python.org or a
> third-party distributor that supplies or links with a newer version of
> Tcl/Tk.

This even caused the blurry radiobuttons experience I had.

> If you are using a Python from any current python.org Python installer
> for macOS (3.9.0+, 3.8.0+, or 3.7.2+), no further action is needed to
> use IDLE or tkinter. A built-in version of Tcl/Tk 8.6 will be used.

I ran my code with IDLE and it works great! Although I still am not able to change the buggy system tcl tk provided by Apple.